# Merge code using Sourcetree

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree with Bitbucket git. I am working on a project with other developers. One of them made a branch and uploaded some changes, and now I can't pull the code since I have some changes on my local repository.

Every time I try to pull the code, I get this error from Sourcetree:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull
    --no-commit origin branch_dev_playerservice 
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref branch_dev_playerservice Completed with
errors, see above.
```

So how can I merge the code using Sourcetree?

Comment: Do a `git fetch` with the prune option marked before. looks like your remote branch is deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can **select fetch from all remotes** to fetch first. Then in **Log/History** (show remote branches), double click **origin/branch_dev_playerservice** -> checkout new branch -> ok.

Now in your local repo, you also have a branch `branch_dev_playerservice` which contain the team’s work.